# How can I run a serial read in the background without disrupting the MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

I m building a GUI with PyQt5 which acts as a visual data representation for a counter.
Now, i would like to run a hourly serial read on a counter which reads the archived deviation data and saves it into a file. The code itself works perfectly but when i try to combine it with the GUI, things get tricky.

The Problem: On the first run of the Program, it should simply read the serial port first and then assign the values to the displayed variables on the GUI. When i try it, obviously the Main Window crashes because the file is empty at first, so there is no data to assign.

I tried to use "threading" as so but i run into the same problem.:

```
    def thread(self):
        t1 = Thread(target=self.Operation)
        t1.start()

    def Operation(self):
        while True: 
            result = read_data()
            if : 
                print(" done reading data! ")
                break
```

I also tried using two separate windows, a Start Window which is only for the serial read (without any visible parameters on screen) and the Main Window which gets the newly read data and visualizes it and after a specific countdown it switches to the first window and updates it with the new data. But this doesn't work either because the second Window although it opens, the code in it isn't running.

This is the serial read code:

```
 while True: 
      result = read_data()
      if final character_found:
             self.countdown_timer.start(1000) # Reset the Countdown
             self.countdown_duration = 10 
             break
```

And this is the Main Window GUI Code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        etc...
  
     
        self.start_countdown()
        self.thread()   
 
       
    #-----------------START COUNTDOWN TIMER FUNCTION----------------
    def start_countdown(self):
        self.countdown_timer.start(1000) [ms]
        self.thread()
        
    def update_countdown(self):
        if self.countdown_duration >= 0:                         # Countdown Timer
            mins, secs = divmod(self.countdown_duration, 60)
            timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)      # Countdown Timer Format
            self.countdown_label.setText(f"{timeformat}")
            self.countdown_duration -= 1
        else:
            self.countdown_timer.stop()                       
            self.countdown_label.setText(" Daten neu lesen ")
            etc..

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
       etc..
```

Its clear to me that this is a very specific problem but any help or new ideas on how to solve this, are appreciated.

FYI: I m a beginner at working with PyQt5, so don't judge the code too much but i m open for any advice :)

Comment: Have a separate module doing the serial reading. The main window should have a _slot_ that listens for new data coming in and draws it to screen when it does. The serial read module should have a _signal_ that emits the data when it's read. The serial module needs either a thread, or you can probably get away with a qtimer to trigger the reads.

Comment: @101 Interesting, I'll give it a try. So the main window waits for the signal of the serial module to pop up, right?

Comment: There seems to be a problem either in your initial approach or your explanation. You say that you "run a hourly serial read which reads the data and saves it into a file", but then you say that the program crashes because the file is empty. Two questions arise: 1. why can't you just add a check to verify that the file actually exists? 2. most importantly, why do you need to read the file, instead of directly accessing the serial port? In any case, Qt provides the QSerialPort class (which is asynchronous and should work fine for most cases), but if you do need to use threads and must interact »

Comment: » with the UI, remember that you **must** use QThreads and proper signals, since UI elements are ***NOT*** thread-safe and should never be accessed from external threads. Do some research on the topic, as there are plenty of resources about it even here on SO. Finally, be aware that editing pyuic generated files is considered bad practice and is always discouraged (as also suggested by the warning on top of those files); the only *proper* way to use such files is by following the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @user22512985 yes it's generally a better design to have your _view_ separate from your logic (in this case serial reads). Qt provides signals and slots to easily send info between different QObjects.

Comment: @musicamante Yea i noticed that aswell, thanks for the advice about not editing pyuic generated files. Second, there is a "check" if the data has been read but it wont execute because there are no values assigned to the variables in the first place. I m also setting them up in the "setupUI", i m guessing thats why. Sorry if i cant articulate it well enough.

Comment: Then the same concept applies: if no variable exists yet, assign a default one or *do not* set widgets values if that's what causes the problem. You need to **think** about what happens and when, and then structure your code accordingly. Unfortunately, unless you provide a valid [mre], we'll never be able to help you, but before that I strongly suggest to take your time to patiently think about the whole program and how logic and UI are related. And remember that the UI cannot be accessed by other threads, as well as timers can **not** be started/stopped from threads different from their own.